# Covariance of $2$ variables

Tags: probability, statistics

I am given two random variables $X$ and $Y$. I am also given that $\mathbb{E}(Y|X)=\mathbb{E}(Y)=\mu_y$ and $\mathbb{E}(X)=\mu_x$. So if I need to calculate the covariance of $X$ and $Y$, $\sigma_{x,y}$, am I right to say the following:

$
\begin{align}
\sigma_{x,y} &= \mathbb{C}(X,Y)\\
&= E(XY) - \mu_x\mu_y\\
&=E(X)E(Y) - \mu_x\mu_y\
=0
\end{align}
$

Comment: Yes, provided you can explain why E(XY)=E(X)E(Y).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following properties of conditional expectation:
$$E[Y g(X)] = E(E[Y g(X) | X]) = E(g(X) E[Y|X])$$
which holds for any random variables $X,Y$ and (measurable) function $g$.

So based on you assumptions, you are justified to say $E[XY] = E[X] E[Y]$ but you have to be careful with the reasoning.